# Merge multiple xml files into one using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Say, here are my XML files

XML file 1

```
<Root>
    <Parent>
        <Child>1</Child>
        <child>2</Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
         <child>3</Child>
         <Child>4</Child>
    </Parent>
 </Root>
```

Xml File 2

```
<Root>
    <Parent>
       <Child>5</Child>
       <Child>6</Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>7</Child>
        <Child>8</Child>
    </Parent>
 </Root>
```

Resultant XML File (as per my requirement)

```
<Root>
    <Parent>
       <Child>1</Child>
       <Child>2</Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>3</Child>
        <Child>4</Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
       <Child>5</Child>
       <Child>6</Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>7</Child>
        <Child>8</Child>
    </Parent>

 </Root>
```

In following function, I have provided paths of xml files to be combined in a string array and trying to merging them

```
private void BindDataInGrid(string[] argFilePaths)
{
    XDocument tempFile = XDocument.Load(argFilePaths[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < argFilePaths.Length; i++)
    {
        tempFile.Descendants("Parent")
           .Union(XDocument.Load(argFilePaths[i]).Root.Descendants("Parent"));
    }
 }
```

In tempFile, there are records only from first file not from others.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ae35ca/merge-2-xml-files-into-single-xml-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: You need to save `tempFile` at the end of the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'm sorry as I forgot to mention that I don't want to save resultant file permanently. I solved it, myself accordingly.

```
private void BindDataInGrid(string[] argFilePaths)
{
    List<Parent> recordsList = new List<Parent>();

        for (int i = 0; i < argFilePaths.Length; i++)
        {
           recordsList.AddRange
               (
                     XDocument.Load(argFilePaths[i]).Root.Descendants("Resident")
                     .Select(data => new Parent()
                     {
                         Child1 = data.Element("Child1").Value,
                         Child2 = data.Element("Child2").Value,
                     }).ToList()
                );
        }
}
```

used recordsList as data source.